# PDF of $Y=\min(0,X)$ when PDF of $X$ is $\frac34(1-x^2)$ on $(-1,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable with density $f(x) = (3/4) (1-x^2).$ Range is $-1 < x < 1.$ I have to find probability distribution of $Y = \min(0,X).$ I know that distribution function could be written as 
$$F(t)= P(\min(0,x) \le t) = P (0 \le t) + P (x \le t) - P (0 \le t, x \le t).$$

I know that $P(x \le t)$ is (from the integral of density) $(3/4)t - t^3/4 + 1/2.$ Could you help me with the rest ?

Comment: I have edited your post for better readability of the mathematical expressions. Please check to make sure I have not changed your meaning.

Comment: Hint: When is $Y=\min(0,X)$ equal to $X$? When is it equal to $0$?

Comment: I know that is X, when x is less than 0, and 0 when it's more than 0. I have a graph od this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry, we have $\mathbb P(X>0) = \frac12$ (you can verify this by computing $\int_0^1 f(x)\ \mathsf dx$). Since $Y=0\iff X>0$, it follows that $\mathbb P(Y=0)=\frac12$. For $-1<y<0$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) &= \mathbb P(X\leqslant y)\\ &= \int_y^{-1} f(x)\ \mathsf dx\\ &= 
\int_y^{-1} \frac34\left(1-x^2\right)\ \mathsf dx\\ &= \frac12 + \frac34 y - \frac14 y^3.
\end{align}
Now, since $\mathbb P(Y=0)>0$, $Y$ is not a continuous random variable, and does not have a density function. Instead we consider its cumulative distribution function:

$$
\mathbb P(Y\leqslant y) =
\begin{cases}
0,& y < -1\\
\frac12 + \frac34 y - \frac14 y^3,& -1<y<0\\
1,& y\geqslant 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Why are you using density of x while computing pdf of y ?

Comment: Something like this, but for min (not max)?

Comment: Yeah, it's for max but is very small mistake.

Comment: Ah, I much more frequently encounter $\max(\cdot, 0)$ than $\min(\cdot, 0)$ so I overlooked this. I'll correct it.

Comment: Agree it's a small mistake, but good to fix it for whomever may look here later.

Comment: @BruceTrumbo Done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much rigor is required, but
intuitively in order to get $Y$, the the negative values of $X$
are not changed and the positive ones all become 0.

I have noted that $X$ can be simulated as twice a BETA(2,2) random variable minus 1. (Showing that might be worthwhile in its own
right.)
You say you have a plot of the CDF of $Y$, but
something is not right with what has gone before. (In my
experience hints from @Did are almost never to be ignored.)

So here are plots of the
empirical CDFs (ECDFs) of $X$ and $Y$, which with 10,000 simulated
points should closely imitate the CDFs. Maybe at the graphs, then finish the theoretical development.
(R code is included just in case you might want to look at that also.)

```
 x = 2*rbeta(10^4, 2,2) - 1;  y = pmin(x, 0)
 mean(x); sd(x)
 ## 0.006255087  # approx E(X) = 0
 ## 0.4525312    # approx SD(X) = 1/sqrt(5)
 mean(y); sd(y)
 ## -0.1873947   # approx E(Y) = -3/16
 ## 0.2556479

 par(mfrow=c(1,2))  # enables 2 panels per plot
   plot.ecdf(x, pch=20, ylab="ECDF", xlab="x", 
       main="X ~ 2BETA(2,2) - 1")
     abline(v=0, col="green2")
   plot.ecdf(y, pch=20, ylab="ECDF", xlab="y", 
       main="Y = min(0,X)")
   abline(v=0, col="green2")
 par(mfrow=c(1,1))  # resume default single panel
```

[image]

Comment: Dunno how you arrived at this result but indeed X=2Z-1 where Z is Beta(2,2), with density 6z(1-z) on (0,1).

Comment: @Did: Graph is inverted parabola, so BETA(2,2) comes to mind. In applications, BETA family is often stretched or shrunk to fit a useful interval.